# Find an example $\mu(\lim\inf A_n)<\lim\inf(\mu(A_n)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space, let $\mu$ be the counting measure. let $\{ A_n \}$ be sets sequence.

Give an example such that $\mu(\lim\inf A_n)<\lim\inf \mu(A_n)$

I consider to take $A_n=\{n,n+1,\cdots\}$

Then $\lim\inf A_n=\emptyset \implies \mu(\lim\inf A_n)=0$ but $\lim\inf (\mu(A_n)=\infty$ .

I am not entirely sure my example is correct , is it ?

I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: your example looks good to me

Comment: Your example is fine. You can replace the counting measure by on $\mathbb{N}$ by $\mu(n)=2^{-n}$ and the same example works well, but the measure is finite.